# How to color a line in SFML?

Tags: c++, colors, sfml

this is my code in sfml, I am trying to color the line but for some reason, it keeps giving me error. Can I get an advise??

```
sf::VertexArray lines(sf::Lines, line.size()-1);

for (int i = 0; i < line.size()-1; i++) 
{
    lines[i].position.x = c[i].x;
    lines[i].position.y = c[i].y;
}
window.draw(Lines);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, and what exactly is not working? Is your line not colored? does your program crash? This information will make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: Also, it's certainly not the problem but pascal casing variable names is confusing, consider camel casing instead. And just speculation, but i'm not convinced `line.size()-1` is correct, are you sure it shouldn't just be `line.size()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the member `color` of the vertices in your vertex array. For example :

```
sf::VertexArray lines(sf::Lines, line.size()-1);

for (int i = 0; i < line.size()-1; i++) 
{
    lines[i].position.x = c[i].x;
    lines[i].position.y = c[i].y;
    lines[i].color = sf::Color::Green;
}
window.draw(lines);
```

See [this link](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-vertex-array.php#a-simple-vertex-array) for more information.